# Postgresql Very Large Insert - way to monitor or batch?

Tags: postgresql, insert, bulkinsert, hl7-fhir

I'm working with the newly released [MIMIC-IV dataset](https://physionet.org/content/mimiciv/2.2/) and trying to convert it to FHIR. I have mostly been able to follow the [instructions here](https://github.com/kind-lab/mimic-fhir) with a few small modifications. However, when I get to the following command:

```
psql -f create_fhir_tables.sql
```

I run into issues. That script calls create_fhir_tables.sql, which looks something like this - [full file available here](https://github.com/kind-lab/mimic-fhir/blob/main/sql/create_fhir_tables.sql):

```sql
SET client_min_messages TO WARNING; -- ignore notices, lots of small ones for drop tables
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS mimic_fhir CASCADE;
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS fhir_etl CASCADE;

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS mimic_fhir;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS fhir_etl;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
...
-- data resources: observations
\echo fhir_observation_chartevents
\i fhir_observation_chartevents.sql

\echo fhir_observation_labevents
\i fhir_observation_labevents.sql
\echo Chartevents D Items
...
```

And the file works, or at least, all of the commands except for the above work. The problem I run into with the above two inserts is the volume (which my computer apparently can't handle). All insert scripts can be [found here](https://github.com/kind-lab/mimic-fhir/tree/main/sql), with the above two specifically [fhir_observation_chartevents.sql](https://github.com/kind-lab/mimic-fhir/blob/main/sql/fhir_observation_chartevents.sql) and [fhir_observation_labevents.sql](https://github.com/kind-lab/mimic-fhir/blob/main/sql/fhir_observation_labevents.sql). The above two inserts are for 313,645,063 and 118,171,367 rows respectively.

The rest of the script includes inserts of up to ~9 million rows of the same types of objects, and ~54 million rows of different types of objects. However, for the above, I've let the script try to run for more than 12 hours, and it still doesn't finish. Now running the entire script without the two above does take almost 2 hours, so running the entire thing may well take over a day. But I was wondering if there was a way to either monitor the progress on these extremely large insert statements, or batch them into smaller ones and monitor those inserts so I could at least be sure that it's still working and that something isn't freezing partway through?

Comment: Consider modifying the problematic scripts to run a loop in an anonymous block to process in subsets; e.g., for _fhir_observation_lab_events.sql_ select for a range of _labevent_id_ values. `COMMIT` after each pass through the loop and use `RAISE NOTICE` to report on progress.